# How to get local storage data into URL?

Tags: javascript, php, json, local-storage

I saved my deviceID in the local storage of the browser with javascript:

```
<button onclick="store()" type="submit">Zoeken</button>
<script  type="text/javascript">

    //Store deviceID in local storage on button click
    function store(){
        var inputDeviceID= document.getElementById("deviceID");
        localStorage.setItem("deviceID", inputDeviceID.value);
    }
</script>
```

Now I want to look with php if any data is stored into the local storage and if there is data stored when opening the page go to that URL path, ../sigfoxapp/?deviceID=1B2E4F

```
$FOLDER = '../sigfoxdata/';
$dir = scandir($FOLDER);
$file = $_GET['deviceID'].'.json' ?: 'DEMO.json';
$fileUrl = $FOLDER.$file;
```

Comment: localStorage is saved in the user's browser. Unless you will send this data to the server - the php will not be aware of these values.

Comment: How can I sent de data to the server so my browser will open in the right url?

Comment: You can use standard forms or ajax

Comment: This might help you

How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript